# HMS 3D Modeling Kit crashed when upload image at iOS platform

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

[image]

If is there any configuration I missed that cause this crash?

Answer (score 0):

To check whether to configure the agconnect-services.plist file, please refer to the link:https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/cn/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/ios-dev-prepare-0000001062940204#section920419487370